# Sync up Joomla 1.5 with 3

Tags: joomla-user-groups

I apologize if this has been duplicated somewhere already but I did have a question Im hoping someone can help answer! So to lay the back story, I work for a non profit that is running Joomla 1.5 and we have been looking to migrate and upgrade for some time. There have been a few road bumps:

- We havent had the staff to fully devote time to do this
- The website cant be down very long
- We have dozens of people constantly updating the site at all hours of the day and night

Now we had hired a consultant (prior to me being hired) to migrate us over to a Joomla 3 dev server. He migrated the theme, posts, images and everything. It actually looks great and functions perfectly. The problem is that the content is from Christmas. So I have been tasked with creating a way to keep the two in sync (production 1.5 with dev 3.x) until we can finally get a day to tell everyone to stop posting so we can update. Now I am way more familiar with Wordpress so when it comes to Joomla I have no idea.

Long story short is there a way that I can:

1. Sync a couple of tables (maybe with an add-drop-table)
2. rsync a folder

In order to sync up the posts and changes without having to do a complete and full 1.5 to 3.0 migration every single time. Thanks!

Comment: What is being posted - articles?  Which tables are you concerned about?

Comment: Im still fairly new to Joomla but from what I can see its all the articles, media and likely just all of the plugin data.

Comment: Well, without specifics, I can only suggest that you look at writing a content plugin for J1.5 (quite simple) .  It fires an event at `onAfterContentSave`.   In that code, you'd examine the article being posted on the J1.5 site, and write the code to do the same on the v3 site.  It's going to get messy simply because there's more to an article on V3 than just a record in the #__content table.   Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question right, you want to show visitors the old J1.5 site while finishing the new site, but keep adding content that will be visible on both sites?

My recommendation would be to add any new content (articles) to the new Joomla 3 site, and use  an [RSS feed](http://kb.siteground.com/how_to_enable_rss_in_joomla_15/) to display the same content on the old J1.5 site. That way the Joomla 3 site is always updated with the latest content, while you still display this to visitors of the old site during development.

You might have to customize the RSS feed and the RSS reader to fit your needs, but it should be fairly straight forward to set it up.